# How to make a 3D tensor into one_hot encoding

Tags: python, pytorch

for example ,labels is a groundtruth, **labels** size is [4,224,224] where 4 means batchsize ,224 means h and w,  labels dtype is torch.int64, in my training code ,label's pixel from 0 to 255 .I use my network to Semantic segmentation

Comment: what is your question? what are you trying to do?

Comment: So you have 256 integer labels, from 0 to 255?

Comment: I don't know How to make a 3D tensor into one_hot encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it seems like you would like 256 integer labels, from 0 to 255. This can be done by the following:

```
# let a be the (4, 224, 224) dim tensor
labels = np.stack([(a == i).int() for i in range(256)])
print(labels.shape) #(256, 4, 224, 224) dimensional one-hot encoding
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks,@ccl, I modify your code `labels = torch.stack([(a == i).int() for i in range(256)])`,and put it to GPU ,It looks like the calculation will be faster